# Fluent NHibernate automapping problem with 2 class refrencing same class

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

for example:

```
public class Foo
{
   IList<Bar> bars;
}

public class Bar
{
   public Foo ParentFoo;
}

public class NewBar
{
   public Foo ParentFoo2;
}
```

The mapping that automapping generates is for the last class referencing the Foo class. The mapping for Foo class is :

```
<bag name="Bars">
  <key>
    <column name="ParentFoo2_id" /> 
  </key>
  <one-to-many class="Bar" /> 
</bag>
```

I am using Fluent NHibernate 1.1 with NHibernate 2.1.2.4000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i moved to fluent nhibernate v1.2 , and it seems everything is working fine now.